# Why do BNF specifications of C-like languages define expressions in terms of seemingly unrelated parent expressions?

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages

Backus-Naur Form specifications for the grammars of languages like like C or C++ build up expressions with counter-intuitive definitions. For instance, a multiplication expression like

```
5 * 3
```

is also a `logical-or-expression` and an `equality-expression` and a bunch of other things it doesn't actually look like, because the grammar makes it an:

- `expression`

  - consisting of an `assignment-expression`

    - consisting of a `conditional-expression`

      - consisting of a `logical-or-expression`

        - consisting of a `logical-and-expression`

          - consisting of an `inclusive-or-expression`

            - consisting of an `exclusive-or-expression`

              - consisting of an `and-expression`

                - consisting of an `equality-expression`

                  - consisting of a `relational-expression`

                    - consisting of a `shift-expression`

                      - consisting of an `additive-expression`

                        - consisting a `multiplicative-expression`.

A snippet from the grammar looks like:

```
<exclusive-or-expression> ::= <and-expression>
                            | <exclusive-or-expression> ^ <and-expression>
<and-expression> ::= <equality-expression>
                   | <and-expression> & <equality-expression>
<equality-expression> ::= <relational-expression>
                        | <equality-expression> == <relational-expression>
                        | <equality-expression> != <relational-expression>
```

So if I were to write a parser that just followed these productions, I'd end up having to interpret the expression `5 * 3` 12 different ways, e.g. by making it an instance of a MultiplicativeExpression class which derives from AdditiveExpression... all the way up to a base Expression class. And that seems very wasteful, since those classes would implement adding, AND-ing, OR-ing, etc. but would simply no-op for the single-term case.

By comparison, the Wikipedia example of BNF makes more sense:

```
<postal-address> ::= <name-part> <street-address> <zip-part>
<name-part> ::= <personal-part> <last-name> <opt-suffix-part> <EOL> 
              | <personal-part> <name-part>
<personal-part> ::= <initial> "." | <first-name>
...
```

The Wikipedia example reads like "a postal address consists of a [...]", whereas C-like language grammars read more like "a [...] can be treated as an expression". Why are C-like language grammars so "polymorphic"?

Comment: I think you meant "naive parser" but I'm not sure what a naive parser would be. The lexer just divides the input character stream into tokens and it has no idea about any kind of expression production.

Comment: What do you think the grammar should look like instead?

Comment: This grammar simply implements the operator precedence rules.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are C-like language grammars so "polymorphic"?

Because that's the way algebra works :-).

The arguments to (for example) a relational expression could be shifts or sums or products (or, for that matter, variables or constants, to say nothing of a variety of unary operator expressions), and all combinations are possible. So you could write out all nine possibilities (and then sixteen possibilities for equality expressions, etc.) (not counting the unary/base possibilities) but the quadratic explosion gets annoying. It's easier to consider each precedence level to include all the more tightly-binding levels as well.

I wouldn't call this polymorphism, really, although you might implement the expression type from a base `Expression` and individual derived types for each operator. The semantic value of every `*-expression` production is then a derived type of `Expression`, and it is not *semantically* necessary to know which one; the production labels are no longer needed.

Comment: A relational expression whose arguments could be shifts/sums/products makes sense, but in a "child" case like `5 * 3`, the relational expression isn't a relation -- and doesn't have arguments; it simply consists of one sub-expression. So relational expressions may be `a < b` or `a > b` or... a shift expression instead of a relation. The shift expression is also just 1 expression, an additive expression. The additive expression is just the multiplicative expression; there's no addition in this additive-expression. So the hierarchy the grammar suggests seems awkward.

Comment: @rici You could improve your answer by discussing the issues with the other extreme, namely having all these "types" of expressions just be different productions of one `expression` nonterminal.

Answer (score 1):

Context-free derivations are trees. Used to represent the syntactic structure of the sentences of a concrete language - hierarchically, as they must - they give rise to somewhat arbitrary taxonomies of substructures, that are not always intuitive (as your example shows), but better than using just letters or symbols.

This is a problem of knowledge representation, which is an art of compromise. Large hierarchies are often problematic in that way. When you think about how awkward it can get for a computational language (or a file system), remember that in the taxonomy of mammals, the hippopotamus and the blue whale are close cousins.